# Is there any latest commands related pushing( password authentication failed) to github?

Tags: aws-devops

I'm learning aws-DevOps . i'm self learner . i'm  encountering an error while pushing. i'm not able to do anything. it's giving frustation[this's the erorr i'm encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSWN9.png)

I tried so many commands like
git remote set-url origin https://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@github.com/tulasi1123/practicegit

git config --global user.name "---"
git config --global user.email "---"

and so many commands ...even i can't find  solution

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors